# Count occurences of item in dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two merged JSON files (saved as dictionary). I would like to count how many times given name occurs. This is a sample what my file looks like:

```
{
'user_id': 1
'id': 1
'name': 'Name1', 
'surname': 'Surname1'
}
{
'user_id': 2
'id': 2
'name': 'Name1', 
'surname': 'Surname2'
}
{
'user_id': 3
'id': 3
'name': 'Name2', 
'surname': 'Surname3'
}
```

And I want to know how many times "Name1" exists in the file. I tried using Counter for each item

```
c = Counter([x['name']])
```

But after every item I get

```
Counter({'Name1': 1})
Counter({'Name1': 1})
Counter({'Name2': 1})
```

How to sum up this?

This is what I get now:

```
response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
file1 = json.loads(response.text)

response2 = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
file2 = json.loads(response2.text)

for i in file1:
    for j in file2:

        if i["userId"] == j["id"]:

            x = list()
            x = i.copy()
            x.append(j)
            print(x)
            c = Counter([x['name']])
```

Comment: Are all dictionaries stored in a list ?

Comment: @AminGuermazi they are not, I can only store each subdictionary in seperate list

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show what you have actually got. See [mre].

Comment: You showed us one sample of invalid JSON, while your last code sample shows that you actually have two files of valid JSON. It's gonna be hard for us to help you unless we understand the actual structure of those files.

Comment: @Jasmijn okay I added correct urls and the sample above is how my file x looks like after those operations, there are some dictionaries

Comment: The code you've shown makes relatively little sense. If `x` is a list, you can't use `x['name']`. And if it is something else, you can't use `x.append`. I've updated my answer to make the most sense of what you have shown so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need one overall `Counter`, not one for each sub-dictionary:

```
response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
posts = response.json()

response2 = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
users = response2.json()

c = Counter()

for post in posts:
    for user in users:
        if post["userId"] == user["id"]:
            c[user['name']] += 1
```

Instead of using `json.loads` with `response.text` you can also just use `response.json()`.

Comment: They are not stored in a list because I can only manage to store every subdictionary in seperate list

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your current counter, not create a new one. To update you can simply add to the counter.

```
c += Counter([x['name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code, the most pressing one is probably the confusion between lists and dictionaries, which are very different types with different interfaces. Next is the quadratic runtime, which you can avoid by having a new dictionary that holds all the users and posts.

```
from collections import Counter

import requests

users = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").json()
posts = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").json()

users_with_posts = {user['id']: {'posts': [], **user} for user in users}

for post in posts:
    users_with_posts[post['userId']]['posts'].append(post)

nameCounter = Counter({user['name']: len(user['posts']) for user in users_with_posts.values()})
```

This assumes you want to do more than just this with the users and posts, otherwise we could simplify the code a bit.

Also note that the runtime is now linear (`O(len(users) + len(posts))`) instead of quadratic (`O(len(users) * len(posts))`).